# How to generate a list of map like {'day': day, 'amount': 0.0} in dart

Tags: list, class, dictionary, dart

Generate a list from the transaction list

i have a dart code contains a list of transaction i want to print a list
of map like {'day': day, 'amount': 0.0} with previous three days data from the transaction list

```
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Transaction {
  final double amount;
  final DateTime date;

  Transaction({required this.amount, required this.date});
}

void main() {
  List<Transaction> transaction = [
    Transaction(
      amount: 100,
      date: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2)),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 200,
      date: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 100,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 300,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 100,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 350,
      date: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 5)),
    ),
  ];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to create a method on `Transaction` which converts a `Transaction` to a `Map<String, dynamic>`:

```
class Transaction {
  final double amount;
  final DateTime date;

  Transaction({required this.amount, required this.date});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => <String, dynamic>{
        'date': date,
        'amount': amount,
      };
}
```

You can then do the following to first filter out which transactions you want to convert and then convert them:

```
  final datetimeNow = DateTime.now();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> transactionsAsMaps = transactions
      .where(
          (transaction) => datetimeNow.difference(transaction.date).inDays <= 3)
      .map((transaction) => transaction.toMap())
      .toList();
```

A complete running example can be found here:

```
class Transaction {
  final double amount;
  final DateTime date;

  Transaction({required this.amount, required this.date});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => <String, dynamic>{
        'date': date,
        'amount': amount,
      };
}

void main() {
  List<Transaction> transactions = [
    Transaction(
      amount: 100,
      date: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2)),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 200,
      date: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 100,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 300,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 100,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      amount: 350,
      date: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 5)),
    ),
  ];

  final datetimeNow = DateTime.now();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> transactionsAsMaps = transactions
      .where(
          (transaction) => datetimeNow.difference(transaction.date).inDays <= 3)
      .map((transaction) => transaction.toMap())
      .toList();

  transactionsAsMaps.forEach(print);
  // {date: 2022-01-08 15:56:24.924579, amount: 100.0}
  // {date: 2022-01-09 15:56:24.924579, amount: 200.0}
  // {date: 2022-01-10 15:56:24.924579, amount: 100.0}
  // {date: 2022-01-10 15:56:24.924579, amount: 300.0}
  // {date: 2022-01-10 15:56:24.924579, amount: 100.0}
}
```

Comment: It is okay and can help to solve one more question. that is can i get a map in same format with the previous three day from DateTime.now();

Comment: @IrshadKP I don't understand what you want? Please update your question so it shows what you want exactly.

Comment: @IrshadKP Updated so the solution now output the last three days only.